# ERROR HiveSyncTool: Got runtime exception when hive syncing

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-hudi

```
ERROR HiveSyncTool: Got runtime exception when hive syncing
org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveSyncException: Could not convert field Type from BIGINT to TIMESTAMP for field updated_at
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.util.HiveSchemaUtil.getSchemaDifference(HiveSchemaUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncSchema(HiveSyncTool.java:185)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncHoodieTable(HiveSyncTool.java:136)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncHoodieTable(HiveSyncTool.java:98)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.syncHive(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.$anonfun$metaSync$4(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:403)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.$anonfun$metaSync$4$adapted(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:399)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.metaSync(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:399)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.commitAndPerformPostOperations(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:460)
```

Timestamp column from RDBMS to hudi and sync into hive

Comment: can you check if this comment https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/2123#issuecomment-778464849 can help you to work around the problem?